# React JS state array empty inside function but items appear in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing this react component to render all chats of an user in a chat app.
The conversation list is acquired from a REST end point and set as a state variable.
When a new message arrives through socket, I'm trying to bring the conversation in the list to the top and mark it in a different color.

The code for that looks like the following:

```
const [conversationsList, setConversationsList] = useState([]);

//When a new message arrives, 
const markNewConversation = (message) => {
  console.log(conversationsList); //Empty array
  let newConversationList = conversationsList.map((conversationElement) => {
    if (conversationElement.thread_id === message.thread_id) {
      conversationElement.date_created = message.date_created;
      conversationElement.new_for.push(user._id);
    }
    return conversationElement;
  });
  console.log(newConversationList);
  newConversationList = newConversationList.sortBy(function (o) {
    return o.date_created;
  });
  console.log(newConversationList); //Empty as well.
  setConversationsList(newConversationList); //Whole screen goes black on this.
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (user._id === null) history.push("/");
    connectSocket();
    socket.on("_messageIn", markNewConversation);
    getThreads().then((threads) => {
      threads.forEach((thread, index) => {
        let allParticipants = thread.thread_participants;
        threads[index].other_user = allParticipants.find((participant) => {
          return participant._id != user._id;
        });
      });
      setConversationsList(threads);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
    // returned function will be called on component unmount
    return () => {
      socket.off("_messageIn", markNewConversation);
    };
  }, []);

return conversationsList.map((conversation) => {
 return(//magically appears inside this div.)
})
```

The problem is when a new message arrives, the function receives an empty array and the entire screen becomes empty. I'm not even setting the array to empty anywhere. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is that `//magically appears inside this div.`? How this return actualy looks like.

Comment: @DamianM I'm rendering names of all people in the conversation as a list inside the map return. And the names are actually rendered in ui. But the exact same state array is empty inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

In this function you're mutating objects, this can cause weird errors.

```
let newConversationList = conversationsList.map((conversationElement) => {
if (conversationElement.thread_id === message.thread_id) {
  conversationElement.date_created = message.date_created;
  conversationElement.new_for.push(user._id);
}
return conversationElement;
```

});

it should look like this:

```
let newConversationList = conversationsList.map((conversationElement) =>
     (conversationElement.thread_id === message.thread_id) ? {
         ...conversationElement, 
         date_created: message.date_created,
         new_for: [...conversationElement.new_for, user.id]
    } : { 
        ...conversationElement, 
        new_for: [...conversationElement.new_for]
    }
```

Comment: The array, even before entering this map function is empty. As you can see the first line of `markNewConversation` function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept in javascript of **State Mutating** and we should never mutate the objects directly. Here you are making the mistake is that when new message comes it **replaces whole object** with new one and kind of re-initialize it. So **spread** the state using spread operator before adding new message.
Do like this:

```
 let newConversationList = conversationsList.map((conversationElement) =>
     (conversationElement.thread_id === message.thread_id) ? {
         ...conversationElement, //spread/copy like this before mutating
         date_created: message.date_created,
         new_for: [...conversationElement.new_for, user.id]
    } : { 
        ...conversationElement, //spread/copy like this before mutating
        new_for: [...conversationElement.new_for]
    }
```

Comment: The array, even before entering this map function is empty. As you can see the first line of `markNewConversation` function.

Comment: Yeah it could be empty at start but during runtime it adds and mutates the previous one as we play with the application so avoid mutating them directly without making a copy of it.

Comment: Unfortunately mutating this way also did not work..